Getting "Precondition check failed" when calling gmail api using a service account that impersonates a user
I want to create a nodejs script that uses a service account to call gmail api on behalf of users of a domain. The service account has domain wide delegation enabled, the domain's workspace admin console has given the necessary scope access for domain wide delegation to this service account.
But on running the script which calls the gmail api,
I get "Precondition check failed" error.

Here is the script which shows that I'm doing the authentication and then calling the getProfile API, but I get the "Precondition check failed" error in the API response as mentioned already
Also, the service account setup is done correctly. Also, there are some other functionalities I plan on implementing which requires me to use service account instead of using OAuth tokens.
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path');

const SCOPES = [
    'https://mail.google.com/'
];

const SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE = path.join(__dirname, 'service-account-key.json');
const USER_EMAIL = 'example@test.com'; //changed it to example@test.com just for showing the script

async function authenticateGmail() {
    const auth = new google.auth.GoogleAuth({
    keyFile: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_FILE,
    scopes: SCOPES,
    subject: USER_EMAIL,
  });

    const authClient = await auth.getClient();
    return google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth: authClient});
}

async function getProfile(gmail) {
    try {
        const profile = await gmail.users.getProfile({
            userId: USER_EMAIL
        });
        console.log('Profile:', profile.data);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error fetching profile:', error);
        if (error.response && error.response.data) {
            console.error('API Response Error Data:', error.response.data);
        }
    }
}

async function main() {
    const gmail = await authenticateGmail();
    await getProfile(gmail);
}

main().catch(console.error);


Precondistion check failed normally means that you are using the wrong type of client for the code you are using.
In this case you are using a service account key file which means that you need to use code designed to work with a service account.
Try this:
const {google} = require('googleapis');
const path = require('path');

async function runSample(impersonate) {
    // acquire an authentication client using a service account
    const auth = await google.auth.getClient({
        keyFile: path.join('C:\\Development\\FreeLance\\GoogleSamples\\Credentials\\workspaceserviceaccount.json'),
        scopes: ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/gmail.readonly' ],
        clientOptions: { subject: impersonate },
    });
    console.log(auth.getAccessToken)
    // obtain the gmail client
    const gmail = google.gmail({version: 'v1', auth});


     // Lists the messages in the user's account.

    console.log(auth)
    const res = await gmail.users.messages.list({
        userId: 'me',
    });
    const messages = res.data.messages;
    if (!messages || messages.length === 0) {
        console.log('No messages found.');
        return;
    }
    console.log('messages:');
    messages.forEach((message) => {
        console.log(`- ${message.id} - ${message.subject}`);
    });
}
domain_user = '[redacted]'
runSample(domain_user).catch(console.error);


It worked. Thanks a lot!
